# How do I install Ubuntu Server from USB without internet access?

Tags: system-installation

Can't get past the "Choose a mirror of the ubuntu archive" step in the installation without having internet access, Is there any workaround?

Answer (score 2):

## Install Ubuntu 13.10 - Server X86-64 Without Internet

Step #1 = Physically disconnect the network cable from your computer.

Step #2 = Turn on the computer and boot up the installation disc.

Step #3 = During the installation process you will be prompted regarding the network. Pick "do not configure network at this time".

## Notes:

Note #1 = Once installed Ubuntu will not have eth0 configured, because of this even if you connect the network cable you won't get network access. If you intend to use the network after installation you will need to configure eth0 yourself. I've never done this, and it sounds rather impossible, but I did find this document about it "help.ubuntu.com/community/NetworkConfigurationCommandLine/Automatic". The "Configuring An Interface" section might be of help?

## Additional Resources:

**Video Of Installation Process (MP4 2.98MB):**

Direct link = https://copy.com/iyyduOYjr78U/screen_recording_iu1310sx8664wia.mp4

Stable link = https://copy.com/iyyduOYjr78U

Answer (score 0):

Using win32diskimager to load the iso into the usb stick worked for me.

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2215731&p=12982130#post12982130